# No references appear on template

Tags: natbib, texmaker, templates

I am using the following template found [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/52fb8acc34a287a85245b47f). I want to use `natbib` (or `BibTeX`, which ever is most convenient) to run my references using `nocite{*}`. It gives me an error message: `Package etoolbox Error: Boolean '\ifciterequest' undefined` (and many others) when I uncomment `%\usepackage[sort]{natbib}`. What do I need to do to let me do this?

```
\documentclass[english,11pt]{report}        
%\documentclass[ngerman,11pt]{report}

%\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx, epstopdf}
\usepackage{hgb}
\usepackage{hgbbib}
\usepackage{hgbheadings}
\usepackage{nth}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{breqn}
%\usepackage[sort]{natbib}
\usepackage{Sweave}

\newfloat{rcode}{h!t}{rcode}
\floatname{rcode}{Code Example}

\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

%\newcommand{\ts}{\textsuperscript}


\graphicspath{{images/}}   % where are the images?
\bibliography{bib}  % requires literatur.bib 
\nocite{*}

\author{}
\title{}
\date{}

%%%----------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%%%----------------------------------------------------------
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

%%%----------------------------------------------------------

blah

%%%----------------------------------------------------------
%\bibliographystyle{}
%\bibliography{bib} 
%\nocite{*}
\MakeBibliography
%%%----------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: There are a number of issues. There's a conflict between `natbib` and `hgbbib` packages as both use a different definition for the `\bibhang` command. The `literatur.bib` file is also not compatible with author-year citations. I think it's best not to use templates unless you are familiar with the packages and commands used.

Answer (score 1):

The `hgb`-bundle is meant for people studying and working at the *University of Hagenberg*. It is actually one of the more *thought through* university templates.

The maintainer decided to go with the modern package `biblatex` along with the modern bibliography processor `biber`.

As such, you should not use package `natbib` along with BibTeX. There is in principal a natbib-compatibility mode for biblatex, that you can use.

If you are not required to use this bundle, as you are not a member of said university, you can do whatever you want and not use the packages.

If you are a member of the university, be as *open minded* as the maintainer and go with the future ;-)